# Why isn't my turbulence affecting my grass particles?

Tags: particles

It moves my flowers just fine, but my grass particles are not moving. blend file here: [image]

im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPYFCe1XKOU
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to check hair dynamics in your particle systems to make that work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When i did that, everything stopped moving, even my flowers.